# Why can't we redefine in an implementing class the visibility of methods declared on an interface?

Tags: php, oop, interface

As I understood the interfaces, they are the construction plan that all the classes that implement them will have to respect.

If I want to create several database classes, say one class to manage mySQL and another to manage PostgreSQL, I would create an interface in which I will put all the methods that are required for my site to work, and my two classes `model.mysqlManager.php` and `model.postgresqlManager.php` would implement this interface.

The thing I do not understand is why we can not redefine in our class the visibility of the methods that come from the interface. I know they are implicitly public.

In my case, I would have liked to have this interface:

***interface.iDatabase.php***

```
interface iDatabase {
    public function connectDatabase();
    // other functions
}
```

And theses classes:

***model.mysqlManager.php***

```
class mysqlManager implements iDatabase {

    protected $db;

    const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const DBNAME = 'dbname';
    const CHARSET = 'utf8';
    const USERNAME = 'username';
    const PASSWORD = 'password';


    protected function connectDatabase() {
        if(!isset($this->db)) {
            try {
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::HOST.'; dbname='.self::DBNAME.'; charset='.self::CHARSET.'', self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

***model.postgresqlManager.php***

```
<?php

class postgresqlManager implements iDatabase {

    protected $db;

    const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const DBNAME = 'dbname';
    const CHARSET = 'utf8';
    const USERNAME = 'username';
    const PASSWORD = 'password';

    protected function connectDatabase() {
        //function code
    }
}
```

I do not want to have access to this method from outside my class, but I want all database classes to implement it.

My questions are:

1. How does the interface affect the class that implements it ? Does not it serve only to define the methods that are mandatory to have ?
2. What other way could I use to force my classes to implement this method ?

Comment: `All methods declared in an interface must be public; this is the nature of an interface.` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: Use an abstract class. Let's call it AbstractDatabase and declare   the method connectDatabase as abstract. Depending on what you want to do, you can have your abstract class implementing the interface and postgresqlManager, mysqlManager  both extending the abstract class AbstractDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the interface affect the class that implements it ? Does not it serve only to define the methods that are mandatory to have ?

An interface defines a contract an implementing class must adhere to.

It defines a **public** interface, necessarily. For this contract to be useful for other classes, methods defined on an interface **have to be public**. Private/protected methods are not part of the contract, but part of the internal implementation, and logically not part of the interface. Whatever private/protected methods class `A` has are not of interest to class `B`, since they can't be used anyway.

If a class could change the visibility of a method declared in an interface, it would **not be compliant with the contract**.

> What other way could I use to force my classes to implement this method ?

A common pattern is to have traits that can be used to fullfill the requirements of an interface. Obviously, the methods provided by the trait have to be public as well.

---

If you want to define the internals of a family of classes, interfaces are not the language feature you should be looking for, but inheritance. You can either define the methods fully or partially in parent classes, and use those methods in child classes.

Note that inheritance and interfaces are very different animals, suited for very different purposes, and inheritance comes with trade-offs like increased coupling that interfaces do not.

But if you wanted to go that way you could create something like:

```php
abstract class AbstractDatabase {
    protected abstract function connectDatabase();
}

class mysqlManager extends AbstractDatabase {
    protected function connectDatabase() {
       // do your thing
    }
}
```

By declaring the class `abstract`, it can't be instantiated directly, but has to be extended. And by declaring the method as `protected abstract` you are saying that inheriting classes MUST implement the method to be able to work.

Comment: I could not understand why we could not just declare mandatory functions in the interface, and then implement them in the class with the desired visibility.

From what I understood from your explanation, being able to redefine the visibility of functions in classes would allow different implementations in several classes, and therefore no longer respect the contract that guarantees the same implementation everywhere.

Is it right ?

Comment: I have now understood why an abstract class would be more suitable in my case, but then in which case an interface would be more useful, since all its functions are public?

Could we make in this case an abstract class that we will inherit with only the protected method, and make an interface that we will implement that defines all the functions to fetch the data?

Thank you for your precious help !

Comment: Interfaces define how other classes can use ("interface") with a class. Private metods by definition can't be part of that contract, since other classes do not care about internal implementation details, they only care that certain methods are available with an specific signature. Interfaces are useful anytime you want to define how a class should be used by other classes.

Comment: Think about an hypothetical Pen interface: it could be defined as "it writes if you press the pointy end to a flat, non-glossy surface". You, as user of the class, do not care HOW the pen moves ink from the ink repository to the pointy end You may not even care if it's ink or any other substance. Those are private methods and properties. You only care that it fulfills the "writes by pushing the pointy end" interface. If the method "write by pushing the pointy end" becomes private, then it's no longer a pen, since users of the class can't write.

Comment: Okay!

As I read in other places, the interface is actually like an API. The purpose of the interface is to list the methods that can be used without worrying about their implementation because these methods will give the same result regardless of the means we choose to obtain the result (in our case mysql or postresql ).

It's easier to understand from the point of view of the user who uses the interface (or the API) than the developer who creates the class.

Thank you for everything !

Answer (score 1):

> My questions are:
>
> How does the interface affect the class that implements it? Does not
>   it serve only to define the methods that are mandatory to have? What
>   other way could I use to force my classes to implement this method?

Interfaces define public methods only. The other way for you to achieve what you want is to define an **abstract** class with abstract `connectDatabase` method instead of interface. Just extend that abstract class with your implementation then.

Abstract methods must be implemented in child classes, so this will work like a interface contract for you.